# UITableViewController and Items of a Dissimilar Nature

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Typically whenever I make a UITableViewController, I am accustomed to the items all being of a similar datatype and style. For example a list of images, or rows of usernames, or something like that.

I was helping someone work on a project and the requirement was to have chat bubbles on each side of the screen. This is easy enough, since based on the user, I can just show/hide the bubble accordingly and assign the text on each row. The chat bubble is similar in the sense that it's just text and a timestamp. The "nature" of this bubble is the same, just oriented to the left or to the right.

The part that adds complication, however, is that if someone joins the chat feed at a particular time, they want to show this. Here is an example:

[image]

So as you can see, it's chat bubbles but at 9:23PM, I have to show this new row that indicates someone joined the feed.

I suppose my DTO / databinding object would look like this, now:

- text: String //The text to show (if relevant)
- userId: UUID //the user id who "took action" on this
- actionDate: TimeInterval //the time of join, or chat (can be either)
- actionType: Int //or enum - 0 means they joined, 1 means they chatted
- alignRight: Bool //I can have the API determine context user, and determine if the chat bubble appears on the right/left.

What is an easy way to achieve this binding, however, from a UI perspective? Do I use table footers somehow? Or do I need to just add this "join event" label to each tablecell, and hide it in every case until someone actually joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table views can display more than one type of cell.

Presumably you have a custom ChatCell (or at least you really should). It renders the chat bubble, timestamp and you can set its alignment.

Now you should define a second custom cell such as EventCell. It should have everything you need to render an event such as someone joining.

Once you have the different types of custom cells and you get them registered with the table view, you just code your `cellForRowAt` accordingly.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let someData = someModel[indexPath.row]
    if someData.actionType == .chatted {
        // create, setup and return a ChatCell
    } else {
        // create, setup and return an EventCell
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much!

Comment: question though - do I want to create two xibs? Or how do I visually create the two different uicells?

Comment: @NullHypothesis Not sure, I do everything in code. But two different xibs sounds right.

Comment: but if you do it via code, you're saying you dynamically create/add the labels and everything? And you are doing this dynamic creation inside of the two custom classes that inherit from UICell ?

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of examples and tutorials on creating custom `UITableViewCell` classes. That is beyond the scope of your original question and can't be covered in comments.